# Setar NODE_ENV via linha de comando no Windows

Tags: node.js

Estou fazendo um curso de Node.JS o instrutor executa o seguinte comando para alterar a variável de ambiente `NODE_ENV`:

```
NODE_ENV=production node index.js
```

Porém, esse comando só funciona no Linux. No Windows, recebo a seguinte mensagem:

> 'NODE_ENV' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Como setar a variável de ambiente e executar a aplicação Node em um único comando no Windows?

Answer (score 2):

Para setar a variável de ambiente e executar a aplicação Node com um único comando no Windows, podemos instalar o pacote npm [win-node-env](https://github.com/laggingreflex/win-node-env) como uma dependência global:

```
npm install -g win-node-env
```

Internamente, ele cria uma aplicação com o nome `NODE_ENV.cmd` que seta o valor da variável de ambiente `NODE_ENV` e depois executa o restante do comando. Dessa forma, podemos executar:

```
NODE_ENV=production node index.js
```

Da mesma maneira que executamos em ambiente Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Os comandos são os seguintes:

**UNIX**
`NODE_ENV=development node index.js`

**WINDOWS**
`set NODE_ENV=development && node index.js`

Answer (score 1):

Se você está executando isso do powershell (ou de uma IDE que utiliza o powershell como terminal), você precisa usar o comando

```
$env:NODE_ENV="production"
```

o antigo comando `set NODE_ENV=development && node index.js` só funcionava no CMD.